# algorithm - maximum pair-wise xor

Tags: algorithms, bit-manipulation

Given two integers m and n where m < n find the maximum pair-wise xor sum.
The question is how to choose m distinct integers from 1 to n such that using those m numbers yields the maximum pair-wise xor sum.

The maximum pair-wise xor sum is calculated on a set of integers x as 
F(x) = sum( number_of_bits( xor(x[i], x[j]) ) for i = 1 to k, j = (i + 1) to k )

For example:
if x = [4, 6, 8], let CB(num) return number of 1 bits in the number.
F(x) = CB(4 xor 6) + CB(4 xor 8) + CB(6 xor 8)
= CB(2) + CB(12) + CB(14)
= 1 + 2 + 3
= 6

The brute force solution could be to generate all subsets of size m and then computing the pair-wise xor sum for each and then taking the maximum out of those.  That would be exponential in terms of time.

Comment: The question is missing?

Comment: The question is to return the set of m numbers that give the max pair-wise xoxr sum.

Comment: This is the task that you were given (without attribution), not a proper question. It seems that to find maximum pairwise xor sum (which is pairwise Hamming distance?) partitioning is not needed, if it were at least using xor (Hamming) properties would vastly reduce the set. So what have you tried so far? I think the result could be calculated in constant time.

Comment: So far I tried thinking about generating  all the pairs possible for integers from 1 to n and then sorting them by their xor bit sum.  Then taking the first m distinct numbers from those pairs.  However that didn't yield the maximum possible sum.

Comment: Your approach is a bit too greedy, also are you sure that bit xor sum results could be sorted? Have you tried calculating result wthout partitioning numbers?

Comment: I don't think the sort is the right answer - it was just something i tried as a guess.  I have tried computing the sums of all the pairs say from 1 - n-2, then from 1-n-4 etc. of all the different subsets but i couldn't find a pattern in those

Comment: Say, you have 5 numbers (m = 5) and the bits could be treated separately, what least significant bits would you use to get maximum pairwise LSB xor?

Comment: I think you can start from right to left (LSB to MSB) and try and find a number that doesn't have it set.  For example if i start with the number 1, then i would want to find something that has LSB = 0 (.e.g 2), then i could move onto the next bit and try and find a number that doesn't have it set and so on.